# E-num / get Dummies in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to create a function in **PYSPARK** that get Dataframe and list of parameters (codes/categorical features) and return the data frame with additional dummy columns like the categories of the features in the list
PFA the Before and After DF:
[before and After data frame- Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMk1l.png)

The code in python looks like that:

```
enum = ['column1','column2']

for e in enum:
    print e
    temp = pd.get_dummies(data[e],drop_first=True,prefix=e)
    data = pd.concat([data,temp], axis=1)
    data.drop(e,axis=1,inplace=True)

data.to_csv('enum_data.csv')
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First you need to collect distinct values of `TYPES` and `CODE`. Then either select add column with name of each value using `withColumn` or use select fro each column.
Here is sample code using select statement:-

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    (1, "A", "X1"),
    (2, "B", "X2"),
    (3, "B", "X3"),
    (1, "B", "X3"),
    (2, "C", "X2"),
    (3, "C", "X2"),
    (1, "C", "X1"),
    (1, "B", "X1"),
], ["ID", "TYPE", "CODE"])

types = df.select("TYPE").distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
codes = df.select("CODE").distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
types_expr = [F.when(F.col("TYPE") == ty, 1).otherwise(0).alias("e_TYPE_" + ty) for ty in types]
codes_expr = [F.when(F.col("CODE") == code, 1).otherwise(0).alias("e_CODE_" + code) for code in codes]
df = df.select("ID", "TYPE", "CODE", *types_expr+codes_expr)
df.show()
```

OUTPUT

```
+---+----+----+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| ID|TYPE|CODE|e_TYPE_A|e_TYPE_B|e_TYPE_C|e_CODE_X1|e_CODE_X2|e_CODE_X3|
+---+----+----+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1|   A|  X1|       1|       0|       0|        1|        0|        0|
|  2|   B|  X2|       0|       1|       0|        0|        1|        0|
|  3|   B|  X3|       0|       1|       0|        0|        0|        1|
|  1|   B|  X3|       0|       1|       0|        0|        0|        1|
|  2|   C|  X2|       0|       0|       1|        0|        1|        0|
|  3|   C|  X2|       0|       0|       1|        0|        1|        0|
|  1|   C|  X1|       0|       0|       1|        1|        0|        0|
|  1|   B|  X1|       0|       1|       0|        1|        0|        0|
+---+----+----+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 11):

The solutions provided by Freek Wiemkeijer and Rakesh Kumar are perfectly adequate, however, since I coded it up, I thought it was worth posting this generic solution as it doesn't require hard coding of the column names.

```
pivot_cols = ['TYPE','CODE']
keys = ['ID','TYPE','CODE']

before = sc.parallelize([(1,'A','X1'),
                         (2,'B','X2'),
                         (3,'B','X3'),
                         (1,'B','X3'),
                         (2,'C','X2'),
                         (3,'C','X2'),
                         (1,'C','X1'),
                         (1,'B','X1')]).toDF(['ID','TYPE','CODE'])                         

#Helper function to recursively join a list of dataframes
#Can be simplified if you only need two columns
def join_all(dfs,keys):
    if len(dfs) > 1:
        return dfs[0].join(join_all(dfs[1:],keys), on = keys, how = 'inner')
    else:
        return dfs[0]

dfs = []
combined = []
for pivot_col in pivot_cols:
    pivotDF = before.groupBy(keys).pivot(pivot_col).count()
    new_names = pivotDF.columns[:len(keys)] +  ["e_{0}_{1}".format(pivot_col, c) for c in pivotDF.columns[len(keys):]]        
    df = pivotDF.toDF(*new_names).fillna(0)    
    combined.append(df)

join_all(combined,keys).show()
```

This gives as output:

```
+---+----+----+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| ID|TYPE|CODE|e_TYPE_A|e_TYPE_B|e_TYPE_C|e_CODE_X1|e_CODE_X2|e_CODE_X3|
+---+----+----+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1|   A|  X1|       1|       0|       0|        1|        0|        0|
|  2|   C|  X2|       0|       0|       1|        0|        1|        0|
|  3|   B|  X3|       0|       1|       0|        0|        0|        1|
|  2|   B|  X2|       0|       1|       0|        0|        1|        0|
|  3|   C|  X2|       0|       0|       1|        0|        1|        0|
|  1|   B|  X3|       0|       1|       0|        0|        0|        1|
|  1|   B|  X1|       0|       1|       0|        1|        0|        0|
|  1|   C|  X1|       0|       0|       1|        1|        0|        0|
+---+----+----+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: I am trying to run this code on a large dataframe and its taking a very long time. I am super new to spark do you think this code is not suitable for large data sets?if so is there a way to improve the performance.

Comment: Have you tried Kumars solution. If you have many columns, this solution will not be particularly fast.

Comment: I need to be able to do this over a lot of columns without hardcoding thats the reason I used ur solution, is there a way to run Kumars solution without the hardcoding?

Comment: when I am trying to run df.show(), it is not showing all the dummy columns

Comment: Hello @rahul did you find out a solution? aka to do be able to do over a lot of columns without hardcoding? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the same solution but is scala, maybe this will help someone:

```
val list = df.select("category").distinct().rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect()
val oneHotDf = list.foldLeft(df)((df, category) => finalDf.withColumn("category_" + category, when(col("category") === category, 1).otherwise(0)))
```

Comment: (The question is about python. This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question).

Comment: I think its always a win-win if somebody is sharing knowledge and the only thing you can do is profit from ysegals answer. I don't like it if people get discouraged for their work by others because these think they have to strictly follow some ruleset (no matter the context or situation).

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to get the PySpark version of pandas "pd.get_dummies" function, you can you the following function:

```
import itertools

def spark_get_dummies(df):
    
    categories = []
    for i, values in enumerate(df.columns):
        categories.append(df.select(values).distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect())
        
    expressions = []
    for i, values in enumerate(df.columns):
        expressions.append([F.when(F.col(values) == i, 1).otherwise(0).alias(str(values) + "_" + str(i)) for i in categories[i]])
    
    expressions_flat = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(expressions))
    
    df_final = df.select(*expressions_flat)
    
    return df_final
```

The reproducible example is:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ("A", "X1"),
    ("B", "X2"),
    ("B", "X3"),
    ("B", "X3"),
    ("C", "X2"),
    ("C", "X2"),
    ("C", "X1"),
    ("B", "X1"),
], ["TYPE", "CODE"])

dummies_df = spark_get_dummies(df)
dummies_df.show()
```

You will get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to make a `DataFrame` from your CSV file.

See [Get CSV to Spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29936156/get-csv-to-spark-dataframe) ; the first answer gives a line by line example.

Then you can add the columns. Assume you have a `DataFrame` object called `df`, and the columns are: [`ID`, `TYPE`, `CODE`].

The rest van be fixed with `DataFrame.withColumn()` and `pyspark.sql.functions.when`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

df_with_extra_columns = df.withColumn("e_TYPE_A", when(df.TYPE == "A", 1).otherwise(0).withColumn("e_TYPE_B", when(df.TYPE == "B", 1).otherwise(0)
```

(this adds the first two columns. you get the point.)