# dynamically create new columns using withColumn function from a list in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to figure out how to dynamically create columns for each item in list(cp_codeset list in this case) by using withColumn() function and calling udf in the withColumn() function in the pySpark. Below is the code that I wrote but it is giving me an error.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col, lit
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType


codeset = set(cp_codeset['CODE'])

for col_name in cp_codeset.col_names.unique():
    def flag(d):
        if (d in codeset):
            name = cp_codeset[cp_codeset['CODES']==d].col_names
            if(name==col_name):
                return 1
            else:
                return 0

    cpf_udf = udf(flag, IntegerType())

    p.withColumn(col_name, cpf_udf(p.codes)).show()
```

The other option is to manually do it but in that case I have to write same udf function and call it with withColumn() function 75 times (which is the size of cp_codeset["col_names"])

Below is my two dataframes and I am trying to get how **result** appears

### P (This is Pyspark dataframe and this dataframe is too large for pandas to handle)

```
id|codes
1|100
2|102
3|104
```

### cp_codeset (pandas dataframe)

```
codes| col_names
100|a
101|b
102|c
103|d
104|e
105|f
```

### result (pyspark dataframe)

```
id|codes|a|c|e
1|100   |1|0|0
2|102   |0|1|0   
3|104   |0|0|1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E-num / get Dummies in pyspark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805663/e-num-get-dummies-in-pyspark)

Comment: Is [that](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#onehotencoder) what you want? BTW why did you set `[pandas]` tag if you need a PySpark solution? It's confusing...

Comment: @MaxU Sorry for confusion.I only have cp_codeset as a Panda dataframe and have P as a pyspark dataframe. I want result in pyspark dataframe. Thank you.

Comment: @Viraj, in this case you have two answers from [piRSquared](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43053959/5741205) and from [Boud](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43053207/5741205) - it should be pretty straightforward to generate Spark DataFrame from Pandas DF...

Answer (score 2):

With this data filtered:

```
cp_codeset.set_index('codes').loc[p.codes]
Out[44]: 
      col_names
codes          
100           a
102           c
104           e
```

Simply use `get_dummies`:

```
pd.get_dummies(cp_codeset.set_index('codes').loc[p.codes])
Out[45]: 
       col_names_a  col_names_c  col_names_e
codes                                       
100              1            0            0
102              0            1            0
104              0            0            1
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `get_dummies` with `join` + `map`

```
m = cp_codeset.set_index('codes').col_names

P.join(pd.get_dummies(P.codes.map(m)))

   id  codes  a  c  e
0   1    100  1  0  0
1   2    102  0  1  0
2   3    104  0  0  1
```

Comment: This gives error of "TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable". If I write P.select("codes").map(m) then it gives "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_jdf'"

Comment: @Viraj why are you writing `P.select`?  That is no where in my code.