# Create Dummy Features for Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, dummy-variable

I'm struggling with creating dummy columns in a PySpark dataframe.

If I have a data frame with 10 columns (1 ID column, 9 object/string columns with n categories)
In Python, I can simply do :

```
cols = list(df.columns)
cols.remove('ID')

df = pd.get_dummies(df[cols])
```

However, I cannot find a single resource where I can create the same result the above code references.

Comment: It's not going to be so easy in spark. The `get_dummies` function works because pandas can enumerate all of the possible values in memory and then create new columns (also in-memory). Hard to do this in a distributed way, unless [you know/collect the possible categories ahead of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805663/e-num-get-dummies-in-pyspark).

Comment: [You can also use `OneHotEncoder`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277576/how-to-handle-categorical-features-with-spark-ml) but it's going to create a vector column. If your ultimate goal is to train an ml model in spark, this is probably the way to go.