# PySpark get_dummies equivalent

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with the following schema:

| Key1 | Key2 | Key3 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | a | "value1" |
| a | a | a | "value2" |
| a | a | b | "value1" |
| b | b | a | "value2" |

(In real life this dataframe is extremely large, not reasonable to convert to pandas DF)

My goal is to transform the dataframe to look like so:

| Key1 | Key2 | Key3 | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | a | 1 | 1 |
| a | a | b | 1 | 0 |
| b | b | a | 0 | 1 |

I know this is possible in pandas using the [get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) function and I have also seen that there is some sort of pyspark & pandas [hybrid function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.get_dummies.html) that I am not sure I can use.

It is worth mentioning that column `Value` can receive (in this example) only the values `"value1"` and  `"value2"`
I have encountered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805663/e-num-get-dummies-in-pyspark) question that possibly solves my problem but I do not entirely understand it and was wondering if there was a simpler way to solve the problem.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

## SMALL EDIT

After implementing the accepted solution, to turn this into a one-hot encoding and not just a sum of appearances, I converted each column to boolean type and then back to integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by on the key columns and pivot the value column while counting all records.

```
data_sdf. \
    groupBy('key1', 'key2', 'key3'). \
    pivot('val'). \
    agg(func.count('*')). \
    fillna(0). \
    show()

# +----+----+----+------+------+
# |key1|key2|key3|value1|value2|
# +----+----+----+------+------+
# |   b|   b|   a|     0|     1|
# |   a|   a|   a|     1|     1|
# |   a|   a|   b|     1|     0|
# +----+----+----+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by group by twice.

```
df = df.groupby(*df.columns).agg(F.count('*').alias('cnt')) \
    .groupby('Key1', 'Key2', 'Key3').pivot('Value').agg(F.sum('cnt')).fillna(0)
df.show(truncate=False)

# +----+----+----+------+------+
# |Key1|Key2|Key3|value1|value2|
# +----+----+----+------+------+
# |a   |a   |b   |1     |0     |
# |b   |b   |a   |0     |1     |
# |a   |a   |a   |1     |1     |
# +----+----+----+------+------+
```

Comment: you don't need to use group by twice. a single `groupBy().pivot().agg(func.count('*')).fillna(0)` should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Just a slight modification of what @samkart did to avoid the error message that I was getting in databricks:

> Invalid usage of '*' in Pivot.

```
data_sdf.groupBy('key1'). \
    pivot('val'). \
    count(). \
    fillna(0). \
    show()
```