# Pyspark - reading a malformed CSV

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a CSV file which I want to read into DataFrame

Here is an example of my file (last column may contains string with spaces):

```
C1 C2 C3
  1  2 ab cd
 11 12 xx yz
5      6 mm nn pl
```

I tried to read this file using:

```
spark.read.csv("myFile",header=True, mode="DROPMALFORMED",sep=' ')
```

But It fails (all rows are malformed)

In order to succeed on reading this file, I need to update it first (remove spaces, add underscores,etc..):

```
C1 C2 C3
1 2 ab_cd
11 12 xx_yz
5 6 mm_nn_pl
```

Is there a way to read the file into CSV without changing it?

I also tried to use the attributes ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace and ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace without success.

```
spark.read.csv("myFile",header=True, mode="DROPMALFORMED",sep=' ', ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace=True, ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace=True)
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: can you iterate through the csv and build a cleaned csv, and try loading that. it seems that you have the following corrections to make: remove leading spaces from each line. c1 & c2 contain text without any separator and c3 has text with spaces that have to replaced by underscore. are there other ways that rows invalid in this csv file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get CSV to Spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29936156/get-csv-to-spark-dataframe) . Read the file as a texfile in SparkContext first, transform your lines in your mapper function, then convert to df.